# Non-destructive video editors

Tags: video-editor, editing, software-recommendation, software

Image editors are classified either as **destructive** (**Photoshop** and **Gimp**) or **non-destructive** (**Darktable**) editors. The former irreversibly hard-codes effects and edits into the image based on the sequence they are applied, whereas for the latter, *all changes to the image are reversible and agnostic to the sequence in which the other effects and changes are applied*.

Adobe Premiere Pro, being the video counterpart to Photoshop, must therefore be a destructive video editor, right? Are there any video editors that are non-destructive instead?

Comment: I've never used Premier, but FCP & DaVinci, whilst saving a 'hard copy' final version, can be re-edited at any time. The original clips are preserved & cuts/cross-fades/titles/colour grading etc are simply overlays in the timeline. The final output does not overwrite the input files, which would imo, make it non-destructive.

Comment: i think you've mis-interpreted the meaning of non-destructive editing. Destructive editors also treats all effects as overlays on the timeline or side panel, but the idea of non-destructive editing is that each effect is independent of all other effects. This is not the case with Destructive editors, which applies each effect in the sequence they are applied: Effect 1 before Effect 2, will look different than Effect 2 before Effect 1.

Comment: Not really. Though I'm from an audio background rather than video, Ive been doing this 40 years, since before you could do it on a computer. If you record a clean guitar; then put it through a reverb & a guitar amp, the order matters, but the original signal remains untouched. That's considered non-destructive. I've never heard of video having a different definition to audio.

Comment: Yes, now you understand the meaning. Like non-destructive audio, **non-destructive** image editing is widely known *outside* of Photoshop. But when it comes to video editing, *is every video editor on the market only destructive then?* ... These 2 terms are independent of whether or not the **original signal** remains. Because of course, when you're in-program, the original signal can always be returned to by pressing undo or hiding layers. Don't worry about that.

Comment: "now you understand the meaning" ...well, I do, but I'm not sure you do. It seems we disagree fundamentally on what the definition is. "is every video editor on the market only destructive" - no, not by my definition & you have yet to clearly explain what *your* definition is.

Comment: In my very first comment.

Comment: like Final Cut Pro and Da Vinci as you say, pretty sure Adobe Premiere also preserves cuts/cross-fades/titles/colour grading etc as overlays in the timeline. That doesn't make it non-destructive though.

Comment: Then you're going to have to accurately define your specific interpretation of "non-destructive", as it seems to be different to everyone else's.

Comment: you're the only one here. there is no one else.

Comment: There were 3 upvotes on my very first comment. I can only assume everyone else lost interest after that. You still need to actually provide a definition, rather than arguing for argument's sake.

Comment: read my 20 comments above. i defined not only in the original post, but repeatedly in the comments. which means you refute the definition which can even be googled: *"Traditional photo editing is ‘destructive’. every adjustment you make permanently changes the pixels in the photo and there’s no way back unless you’ve saved a copy of the original and you’re willing to start again. ‘Non-destructive’ editing is fully reversible. You can go back and undo or redo all of your editing work at any point in the future. "* I apply the same to video editing, but stress **sequentiality**

Comment: OK… sequentially. Apply a cut between 2 scenes, apply a  simple cross-fade, then a LUT. Move the cut, the crossfade moves too & the LUT is reapplied to the new edit. How sequentially would you like?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adobe Premiere Pro, Final Cut Pro and Da Vinci are all non-destructive video editors, although it hasn't been tested in these programs whether the sequence in which effects are applied are independent.